# ASP.Net Core MVC Models returning not valid with UserId FK

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation

Okay so I've run into a bit of an issue and am totally lost at this point on what could possibly be going wrong. I have a project that was already finished using a Login/Registration system I built from scratch. It was pretty simple. I decided to implement the Microsoft Identity Platform so I could add third party authorization using Goggle, Facebook, etc. I have successfully gotten the identty platform added and the login and registration is working. The only issue I have now is my forms for adding a post to the website needs to record the UserId as a foreign key so I can record who created each post.

I have added the UserId as a foreign key to the model but now anytime I try to add a post the ModelState.IsValid keeps returning false, but no model validation errors are being thrown. And when I remove the IsValid check from the controller, it records everything to the database fine, including the UserId... So I am unsure as to why it would be returning false when it clearly records all the data correctly.

Here is my Post Model

```
    public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage ="must be at least 3 characters")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage ="must be 50 characters or less")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [GreaterThan0]
    [Display(Name ="Players on Team")]
    public int PlayersOnTeam { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [GreaterThan0]
    [Display(Name ="Max Players On Team")]
    public int MaxPlayersOnTeam { get; set; }

    // 0 = PC, 1 = PS4, 2 = Xbox One, 3 = PS5, 4 = PS3, 5 = Xbox 360
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    public string Platform { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    public string Language { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [Display(Name ="Group Type")]
    public string GroupType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [GreaterThan0]
    [Display(Name ="Minimum Level")]
    public int MinLevel { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage ="must be at least 10 characters")]
    [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage ="must be 500 characters or less")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="is required")]
    public string GameActivity { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    

    // foreign keys


    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public AdvanceUser Author { get; set; }

    // before I had this set up as which is why the controller uses AdvanceUser.Id, not UserId
    // public string Id { get; set;}
    // public AdvanceUser Author { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Post Controller functions for creating new posts. I've tried both these following examples and both end up doing the same thing. Note that I know it is using the AdvanceUser.Id field in this code rather than AdvanceUser.UserId (I have changed it back and forth, so this isn't the issue. I had it using the UserId field and it still wasn't working

```
 [HttpPost("/lfg/posts/create")]
public IActionResult Create(Post newPost)
{
    if (!loggedIn)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }

    if (uid != null)
    {
        newPost.Id = uid;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return New();
    }
    var currentUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
    newPost.Author = currentUser;

    _context.Posts.Add(newPost);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Dashboard();
}

[HttpPost("/lfg/posts/create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Post newPost)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(uid);

    if (!loggedIn)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }

    // if (uid != null)
    // {
    //     newPost.Id = uid;
    // }

    
    newPost.Author = user;

    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return New();
    }


    _context.Posts.Add(newPost);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Dashboard();
}
```

These are at the top of the class and used for authentication and grabbing the user id of the current user

```
  private string? uid
{
    get
    {
        var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return userId;
    }
}

private bool loggedIn
{
    get
    {
        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Here is my view for adding a new post

```
    @model Post


<div class="container w-75 mx-auto">
    <h2 class="text-center">New Post</h2>

    <form class="shadow p-3 rounded" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Create" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Title"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Title">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="GameActivity"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="GameActivity" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="GameActivity">
                @{
                    foreach (GameActivity activity in ViewBag.allActivities)
                    {
                        <option value="@activity.Name">@activity.Name</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        @* <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="GameActivity"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="GameActivity" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="GameActivity">
                <option value="Raid">Raid</option>
                <option value="Public Event">Public Event</option>
            </select>
        </div> *@

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="PlayersOnTeam"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="PlayersOnTeam" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="PlayersOnTeam">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="MaxPlayersOnTeam"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="MaxPlayersOnTeam" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="MaxPlayersOnTeam">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Platform"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Platform" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="Platform">
                <option value="PC">PC</option>
                <option value="PS4">PS4</option>
                <option value="Xbox">Xbox One</option>
                <option value="PS5">PS5</option>
                <option value="PS3">PS3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Language"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Language" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="Language">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="GroupType"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="GroupType" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <select class="form-control" asp-for="GroupType">
                <option value="LFG">LFG</option>
                <option value="LFM">LFM</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="MinLevel"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="MinLevel" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <input class="form-control" asp-for="MinLevel">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Description"></label>
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Description"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

And lastly, this is my Program.cs class. Just in case its needed

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LFGHub.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
//         CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
//     .AddCertificate();

// builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
//     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
// builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<AdvanceUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddDefaultUI().AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddScoped<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserManager<AdvanceUser>>();

var app = builder.Build();

var serviceProvider = app.Services.GetService<IServiceProvider>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

EDIT:
Here is the AdvanceUser model. I'm not sure what could possibly be incorrect.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using LFGHub.Models;

public class AdvanceUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    public string DestinyUsername { get; set; }

    // public virtual ICollection<Post>? Posts { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

Here is my db context

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LFGHub.Models;

namespace LFGHub.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AdvanceUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Author)
            .WithMany(x => x.Posts);
    }
    //public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GameActivity> GameActivities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    // public DbSet<GroupMember> GroupMembers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsPost> NewsPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to dig into the AdvanceUser object to see what is missing or binded incorrectly before ModelState.IsValid.  ModelState doesn't know anything about the db it is only validating based on the Post class.

Comment: I did look into that and I don't see anything that is incorrect... I have added my AdvanceUser model onto the post so you can see how it is set up. But I see no issues with it.

Comment: Its looks strange that you are using an Author object with a foreign key attribute on it. Normally foreign keys are primitives, or otherwise are set up in the DBContext. Are you sure you are doing that correctly?

Comment: I've added my db context to the post now. And I did define the fk using builder.Entity<Post>()  so I'm not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: You have "[ForeignKey("UserId")]"  but I see nothing that sets it... and it's not a property in the Post model or the page class.  It sounds like that hasn't caused you any issues, though.  Maybe it's this bit: private string? uid ... that doesn't seem like it should be nullable or a string.

Comment: You've made that part of your page model, but it seems like you should do the user's id lookup in a method, and then set it to the Post before adding it.

Comment: Yes this is also curious...`UserId` is not a property of AdvanceUser. As far as I know, it is also not a property defined in your base class (IdentityUser).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. I had to change the Post model foregin key properties as follows:

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public AdvanceUser? User { get; set; }
```

and in my AdvanceUser class I changed the ICollection from a virtual ICollection to just a normal ICollection

```
public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

And then lastly I changed my database context to

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    // Commented this out too
    // builder.Entity<Post>()
    //     .HasOne(c => c.Author)
    //     .WithMany(x => x.Posts);
}
//public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
public DbSet<GameActivity> GameActivities { get; set; }
public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
// public DbSet<GroupMember> GroupMembers { get; set; }
public DbSet<NewsPost> NewsPosts { get; set; }
```

I had noticed that when I looked at the tables in the database it was creating a two userId columns. one called UserId and the other called AuthorId. So I made these changes and its working now! Thanks for all the help guys!